# Android Studio Downgrade

Tags: android-studio, gradle, libgdx

I'm having some Gradle sync issues with LibGDX and from what I've read I need to downgrade to an old version of Android Studio (2.2.3). Unfortunately, Google no longer hosts these old versions on their websites. Does anyone know where I can get it for Mac?

Comment: may i know what's that sync issue ?